# Sorting table of items which load individually and asynchronously from backend

Tags: reactjs

I have a design problem I've been thinking about for close to a year. I have a solution currently, but it's not very satisfactory so wanted to ask for help. Disclaimer: I asked this question over a year ago ([Pattern for sorting a table on values of its child components when the values are loaded asynchronously after the table has been rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508706/pattern-for-sorting-a-table-on-values-of-its-child-components-when-the-values-ar)) , and received no answers so trying again with more context.

**What I'm trying to do**

Premise is this. I have an app which renders a table of items. So far so good, but each item is an "expensive" operation on the backend and the API calls (async) can take a few seconds. Each of these items share common fields and therefore I'd like to render them in a sort and filterable table.

Individual requests might take different amount of times and I'd like to show data as soon as available instead of waiting for everything to be available.

**How this has been modelled**

The way I've modelled this is that I have a custom component "StockLoaderTable" which holds a list of "StockItem".

```
<StockLoaderTable>
 <StockItem ticker="abc" dispatcher={dispatchDataUpdate}/>
 <StockItem ticker="bcd" dispatcher={dispatchDataUpdate}/>
 ...
</StockLoaderTable>
```

** The approach that sort of works **

I have created a custom hook for my backend API to call and evaluate a given stock and each StockItem uses this hook to go and fetch a bunch of details.

So far so good all works nicely. However, I would now like to be able to sort/query/filter the overall table, and unfortunately all the data is now stored in the item components themselves and the parent has little way to get to them. In addition, individual evaluations may fail (for a bunch of reasons), so "error" is a valid state for the child to end up in.

So the way I solved this for now is that I provide a useReducer hook to the child items which they can use to inform the parent whenever their data updates. The parent then keeps a "copy" of the data for each child in itself and applies filter/sort based on this. This means I effectively have the data stored twice and this doesn't seem very elegant to me.

**Alternative considered that didn't work**

I considered just doing data fetching in a list/loop in the parent, but the rules of hooks don't like me doing that.

**Alternative I'm currently considering**

Storing data once in a central context/db of some sort. The child items would still be responsible for updating and rendering themselves, but at least I only store the data once in the app.

About to refactor this part of the frontend and would appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: Did you take a look at react-query? maybe the useQueries hook can be interessting for you, sicne you have a varibale amount of rows (each its own query in useQueries), you have caching as well, so you coul daccess it at differnet lveles if need, e.g. at row level or global level, also you get a rerender if data changes and you can get some resolved queries while others are still loading. https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQueries

Comment: @Domino987 thanks for your reply. Yes, I use react-query within my custom hook to fetch the data, and that is useful indeed. However, it doesn't solve my problem of needing to have a sortable collection of data because, as with my failed experiment, the rules of hooks prevent me from dynamically using/looping on it

Comment: I added en exmaple as an asnwer so we can talk abut the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using useQueries of RQ could result in something like this right?

```
 const results = useQueries([
   { queryKey: ['post', 1], queryFn: fetchPost },
   { queryKey: ['post', 2], queryFn: fetchPost },
 ])
and sort it with

const sortedResult = React.useMemo(() => [...results].sort((a,b) => a.data.title.localeCompare(b.data.title)), [results])
```

Comment: Ok, now I see that is an interesting idea. One question though. I created a custom hook that deals with making calls to my backend including AuthX etc. As I understand useQueries I need to hand it an async function not another hook, so therefore it seems like I'd need to refactor my custom hook into such an async function. This could be done, but I fear I will end up with some duplicated code as I still, in parts of the frontend, just query one stock at a time and use my custom hook for that. I will have a play with your suggestion though and see where it gets me.

Comment: Yes it's not the hook itself but the same parameters. So just pass the same key and async functions you are already using for the custom hook but as an array of objects. And since RQ uses caching, the custom hook and useQueries will not call the backend if there is already data present . That should work nicely for your usecase.

Comment: So this looks promising as of current experiments. Now I just have one annoying problem. I need to display failed and loading tickers, but the way useQueries works is that it has no reference to the queryKey in the result so I have no way of mapping the results to what the user asked for as until I have a success load the result has no reference to the stock symbol. gist illustrating code and how return is a problem https://gist.github.com/Ancient87/e393bd8a52543f71896407f2b8e0f597

Comment: Of course you do ;).   if you add the index to the for each:.  if (result) { const key = queryArray[i].queryKey;
      if (result.data) {
        const data = result.data as IStockInfo;
        const ticker = data.ticker;
        stockData[ticker] = data;
      }
    }

Comment: Of course - well now I feel stupid. So thanks so much Domino987 I got it working now with your solution after a lot of sweat and tears. Full code for the component is here FYI https://gist.github.com/Ancient87/0c95238b0eeae3838323910ae636b73e. Only slight problem left is that now after sorting my queryArray index no longer matches and I end up with the wrong ticker for the data. Need to think about that one some more